# Authentication based on cookies in Angular 5

Tags: php, angular, express, angular5

I am developing a website using **Angular 5** and **Express JS**. On successful login, I am sending **access_token** cookies from the server to client. Cookie is setting successfully in the browser. But when I am sending other requests after login, access token cookie is not sending automatically like in usual client server communication ( session cookies). And my question is

- Is my implementation correct?
- Do I need to use interceptors for this?
- Do I need to use headers for sending token instead of cookies?

Comment: When using cookies, they are received at next page load, they are not available immediately - you'd need to force page refresh to use at time of service

Comment: So for angular app cookies are not usual right?

Comment: What Sam Swift said and since Angular renders views in a single page, page refresh never happens unless explicitly done and hence cookies don't render much help. Better way is to send tokens in headers which can then be stored on client side(localstorage) using HTTP interceptors although interceptors are optional

Comment: did you configure a proxy on your Angular development server in order to run your client and your server on the same hostname and port ?

Comment: Both are running on same server. But I am not aware of setting a proxy. Where can I find more info about it?

Comment: Forget what I asked, cookies are domain specific (not port specific) then if you run both your server and your client on your machine, your cookies should work properly

Comment: could you provide what the `Set-Cookie` header looks like ?

Answer (score 1):

If your server and client are running on a different port, then you are missing [withCredentials](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials) in all of your `XMLHttpRequest`

You should use the following interceptor :

```
@Injectable()
export class CustomInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor() {
    }

    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {

        request = request.clone({
            withCredentials: true
        });

        return next.handle(request);
    }
}
```